# no android platform found error on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am running a Xamarin app on my Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition IDE for the first time and I am getting this error

> No Android platform found. Please click here to open the SDK Manager and install an Android SDK Platform.

This is my Android SDK Manager installed Packages

[image: Installed Packages]

This is the Xamarin options set at Visual Studio Options

[image: Visual Studio Options]

Why am I getting this error? How to make my application working?

Comment: Can you add some IDE/monodroid logs from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Log` to your question? Secondly, when does the error appear for you? Can you please explain the steps you took?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Android SDK Location to **%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Android\android-sdk** or change the SDK path to some other path that is without space. I have previously faced issue if having [space] in the SDK file path.